# How can I extend this object detection pytorch program to detect and classify more than one class?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, object-detection, torch

I followed [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-your-own-object-detector-pytorch-vs-tensorflow-and-how-to-even-get-started-1d314691d4ae) tutorial for building an object detector and now I am trying to expand it to recognise more classes.

This object detection algorithm only works for one class (raccoon), however it is possible to train the neural network with bigger datasets to recognise more classes.

It uses a pretrained faster_rcnn_resnet50 network.

Could someone help me adapt the code so that it can distinguish more than one class?

Thanks in advance!

```
class RaccoonDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, root, data_file, transforms=None):
        self.root = root
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.imgs = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, "images")))
        self.path_to_data_file = data_file

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # load images and bounding boxes
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root, "images", self.imgs[idx])
        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        box_list = parse_one_annot(self.path_to_data_file,
                                   self.imgs[idx])
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(box_list, dtype=torch.float32)

        num_objs = len(box_list)
        # there is only one class
        labels = torch.ones((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
        # suppose all instances are not crowd
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

        if self.transforms is not None:
            img, target = self.transforms(img, target)
            return img, target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgs)
```